# Break LinkedList into Multiple Lists based on number of items in the list

Tags: java, linked-list

My Source `LinkedList` has 20300 items. I need to break this list into sub lists for every 2500 items respectively and the remaining values (300 in this case) should be present in the final `List`.

Please let me know how can i achieve this ?

The Below code is working fine , except for the last 300 values , it is throwing error ..

```
private static List<List<String>> split(LinkedList<String> src, int maxSize){
    List<List<String>> splittedList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    int itemsRemaining = src.size();
    int start = 0;

    while (itemsRemaining != 0) {
        int end = itemsRemaining >= maxSize ? (start + maxSize) : itemsRemaining;

        splittedList.add(src.subList(start, end));

        int sizeOfFinalList = end - start;
        itemsRemaining = itemsRemaining - sizeOfFinalList;
        start = start + sizeOfFinalList;
    }

    return splittedList;

}
```

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: What error do you get? What is the value of start and end at the time you get the error?

Comment: @Freiheit error received is  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: fromIndex(6) > toIndex(2)
 at java.util.SubList.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.AbstractList.subList(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a mistake when computing the end. Rather than

```
int end = itemsRemaining >= maxSize ? (start + maxSize) : itemsRemaining;
```

It should be

```
int end = start + (itemsRemaining >= maxSize ? maxSize : itemsRemaining);
```

Or rather

```
int  end = start + Math.min(maxSize ,itemsRemaining);
```

Notice that in your version for the last elements the end is set to the number of remaining items, rather than the size of the original list.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that recursively calls itself with the original list, a counter, and an empty list (accumulator). In the function, do the following:

Test if the original list is empty, and if so, then return the accumulator. Otherwise, test if the counter equals 300 (or whatever), and if so, then add the next element in the original list to the accumulator, set the "next" of the current element in the original list to null, and call the function with that same next element, zero, and the accumulator, returning the result. Otherwise, call the function with the next element in the list, an incremented counter, and the accumulator, returning the result..

Call the function with the original list, zero, and an empty list. It should return the result.

Since this is obviously a homework question, I hope this helps without doing your homework for you. Since I didn't write this out, there may be issues with off-by-one errors or adding an empty list to the accumulator, but the general algorithm should work, you'll just need to iron it out. Good luck.